# Where is gradle installed?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Gradle to build Android apps, however gradle isn't recognized by Windows (it is not on the path).
How can I know where my current version of gradle is installed ?

Comment: Do you have gradle installed onto your PC? should be in the program files if so

Comment: It's not there ; I never installed it manually.
I literally just opened Android Studio and it started downloading gradle 7.1, for some reason.

Comment: hmm i know i had to download gradle to my PC and make an enviroment variable  for android studio to work for React Native projects